# Capture all of the user's mouse clicks on a website

Tags: jquery, html

Can i capture a user's mouse click on `<a>` tags via jquery *before* the page navigates ? I'd like to send them via an ajax call and record them in a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture any document mousedown or click. Better mousedown perhaps, in order to not be prevented by other click events (via event.preventDefault).

```
document.onmousedown = function (event) {
  if (!event) {event = window.event;}
  console.log("mousedown "+event.target, event);
  // Post the event object here.
};
```

With jQuery:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function (event) {
  console.log("mousedown "+event.target, event);
  // Post the event object here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method to capture all the mouse events like this:

```
capture_mouse_clicks = [];

$('#id').on('click', function(e) {
    capture_mouse_clicks.push({
        event: 'click',
        target: $(this).attr('id'),
    })
})
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can place onclick handlers on tags but your ajax might fail when the page navigates but if server responds quickly then xhr gets cancelled in midway.

You can add a slight JS delay in your code, right after your async ajax. This might help.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to store them in a global array or a global variable which can be accessed throughout the page. You can either capture the entire event by writing a function to capture the event so I would prefer an array with all event objects.

Next when you navigate away from the page, use the window.onbeforeunload event and have an ajax call to do a post call and save the array of objects in your database.

The code for the above two steps is relatively simple.